# add url to wordpress with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url

Here is my portfolio http://portfolio1426.zzz.com.ua/   . In the section 'portfolio' I add my one site. If you press a button 'look at it' you can see a title and description of project. Also there is a link 'Site here'. If you press in it, the link doesnot redirect you to this site, but redirect on page with id 'http://portfolio1426.zzz.com.ua/#work_0'    .      I can't change my html code, or when I add `<a href ='http://ovk.zzz.com.ua/ovk/'> site here </a>`

in description it also doesnot work. I know that the problem is in my PHP-code, but I dont understand what the mistake is.
Here is my PHP-code :

`

  All works
  Sites
  Identica
  Logos

```
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=7');
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                        <div class="mix col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portfolio_item <?php
                        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                        if ($tags) {
                            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                                echo ' ' . $tag->name;
                            }
                        }
                        ?> ">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(600, 600)); ?>
                            <div class="port_item_cont">
                                <h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                 <a href="#" class="popup_content">Look at it
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="hidden">
                                <div class="podrt_descr">
                                    <div class="modal-box-content">
                                        <button class="mfp-close" type="button" title="Закрыть (Esc)">×</button>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                       <img src="<?php $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
                                        echo $large_image_url[0];
                                        ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <? endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: That hyperlink is being generated from `the_content()` in which you're getting that Lorem Ipsum and the `<a href="#work_1">ere</a>` so you'll need to edit the hyperlink in the blog post directly - or in perhaps a different plugin is appending that content.

Comment: i have tried to edit hyperlink in the blog post directly - it does not works. also i installed 2 plugins with adding links - they also don't work :(

Comment: i think i have to edit my php code, but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the_content() WordPress function is removing the html code. The 'Site here' link is not linked.

Maybe your theme is using a filter function that is removing html tags from the post content

Comment: well, i will relook my theme details now :)